# Access VBA change Query criteria via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to change the SQL statement of a query.

This is the following code:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim sqlString As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Query1")

sqlString = "SELECT *all the Tables* FROM tab WHERE (((tab.columname)=*Variable*;"

qdf.SQL = sqlString
```

so my problem is the value of the Variable is not shown...

but it has to ge out of the string so I tried this:

```
sqlString = "SELECT *all the Tables* FROM tab WHERE (((tab.columname)= " & " *Variable*" & " ;"
```

I had to add "Variable" (quotation marks)

this then works half way.

it then uses the value of the variable it is set to but the quotes are missing...

The Goal of this Code is to change the Criteria that shows the data in the query.
The Variable value is as sample LA-85995561.

The way i want to change the value is via SQL statement.

I don't know further from here. thanks for any help!

(I am new to VBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anser is that I had to use different marks:

```
WHERE (((tab.collumname)=""" & strVariable& """));"
```

it's about the """ & part it never made the " in the SQL thanks for all awnsers! brought me to my solution! <3

Answer (score 0):

If `columname` is text, then you can use something like this:

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM tab WHERE tab.columname='" & strVariable & "'"
```

For numeric data type:

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM tab WHERE tab.columname=" & str(lngVariable)
```

Comment: It will imput a Value like this : LA-85995561 
I tryed you'r solution and it gives me Error while compiling... and marks the first ) of the ending part  ));"
did i do someting wrong?

Comment: I don't know what is your goal. I gave an example how to generate SQL text using VBA. You should declare variable strVariable and assign a value you want. Or you want that this query asked user to enter a value?

Comment: Still not clear what is Variable here. VBA variable? You didn't declare it. Parameter of query, which should be requested when user opens the query? Create the working query in query designer first, then replace variable part by VBA variable like in my example. You should generate correct SQL text, which should work in query builder. In your example SQL won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `PARAMETERS`:

This passes a text string:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "PARAMETERS MyNamedSearchValue TEXT; " & _
        "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columname = MyNamedSearchValue")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("MyNamedSearchValue") = "A"
        Set rst = .OpenRecordset
    End With

    With rst
        MsgBox .Fields("MyDateField")
        .Close
    End With

    qdf.Close

End Sub
```

This passes a number:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "PARAMETERS MyNamedSearchValue LONG; " & _
        "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columname = MyNamedSearchValue")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("MyNamedSearchValue") = 100
        Set rst = .OpenRecordset
    End With

    With rst
        MsgBox .Fields("MyDateField")
        .Close
    End With

    qdf.Close

End Sub
```

You'll have to update the SQL to suit your needs.  You could also pass it the name of a stored query rather than writing the SQL within the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Classic example to use parameterization, an industry best practice when using SQL at the application layer like VBA. And since you already use a querydef you can pass parameters easily withe `PARAMETERS` clause to define data type and placeholder.

**SQL** *(save as a stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS VariableParam Text(255);
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE tab.collumname = [VariableParam];
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Dim sqlString As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdf!VariableParam = "LA-85995561"

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()  
' rs CAN BE USED IN FORMS/REPORTS RECORDSOURCES:
' Set Me.Form.Recordset = rst
' Set Me.Report.Recordset = rst
```